# Hiding parent view in Master/Detail pattern

Tags: ember.js

I am building a mobile-first app which therefore needs to be quite economic with screen real-estate and there are cases where when navigating between a **resource** and one of it's sub-routes I want to be able to have the subroute take the place of the `{{outlet}}` but at the same time remove the parent view/template's DOM elements. So if my route were set as:

```
Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('workouts', function() {
        this.route('workout', { path: '/:id' }, function() {
            this.resource('exercises', function() {
                this.route('new');
                this.route('exercise', { path: '/:id' });   
            });
        });
    }   
}
```

And let's say I wanted to start my browsing by looking at a specific workout ("1234") with a list of all the exercises undertook in the workout but without the details. I would navigate to:

```
http://best.app.ever/workouts/1234
```

and when I clicked on a particular exercise I'd want to see the details of that exercise ("123") at:

```
http://best.app.ever/workouts/1234/exercises/123
```

This works without issue but -- as might be expected -- the details of the exercise are inserted into the DOM at the `{{outlet}}` in the **workout.hbs** template. What I'm looking for is a graceful and easy way to replace the parent templates DOM entries (at least for smaller media types).

Extra credit solution which would allow for some sort of subtle animation between states to help the user understand the transition.

---

BTW, I have a working solution which I've convinced myself is more of a hack than the "right way" of doing this in Ember ... it goes like this:

- In the child view (aka, *exercises/exercise*) I have overloaded the default View and add the following:

  ```
  export default Ember.View.extend({
      hideMaster: function() {
          var master = this.$().parents('body').find('#master-screen');
          master.hide();
      }.on('didInsertElement')
  });
  ```

This depends on the "master" (in this case the **workout.hbs** template) having a DOM element "master-screen" that encompases that part of the DOM I want to hide. This type of solution would also lend itself easily to animating states too but I suspect some smart mind out there has a more Ember-like way of doing this ... if so please speak up. :)

Comment: Note: for some reason my original selector of `this.$().parents('#master-screen')` didn't work so I had to add the up-and-down selector you see in my example.

Answer (score 1):

I would be tempted to use the `exercises/index` template to display the list of exercises. That way it’ll be automatically swapped out when you transition into `exercises/exercise`. You could then use liquid-fire to add a graceful transition.

However, that solution won’t allow you to keep the full list of exercises on-screen for desktop browsers. For that case, I’d say the right approach would be to design a component dedicated to the appropriate responsive behaviour. It’d do a similar job to the view you’ve defined, but be far more explicit when you come to look at the templates further down the road.

**Dumb Example:**

exercises.hbs:

```
{{#x-responsive-view}}
  {{#x-parent-content}}
    <ul>
      {{#each exercise in exercises}}
        <li>...</li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  {{/x-parent-content}}
  {{#x-child-content}}
    {{outlet}}
  {{/x-child-content}}
{{/x-responsive-view}}
```

`x-responsive-view` would hide `x-parent-content` if we’re on mobile AND `x-child-content` contains something.

Comment: Yes this looks like a better solution (and I love liquid fire) but I do have a problem in my particular situation that I think means i must go an alternate route ... the *index template* you're referring to (`/workouts/workout/exercises`) would be a list of just the exercises but in fact the user would be on the `/workouts/workout` page where he'd see both a list of *exercises* and *measurements*.